# Recommended approach for admin site and front end using MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to build a website using the MEAN stack and my database schema will be defined using Mongoose. This website will have an admin site, in which I will have all the CRUD operations for the data displayed by the frontend website. As the object model will be the same, if I'm using Java or C# I would compile this classes in a Jar or Dll and use it in my frontend site, along with the DB definitions and repositories (say hibernate)
What will be a recommended approach for reuse this object model in this MEAN scenario? Is it common to have another "folder" in my express setup? What if I want to run the admin site on another port?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have no response yet, one example; Here is a nice scaffold that im working with which uses also JS, not C or Java and is a [fairly good example](https://github.com/wolfdogg/expressBuilder/) of what your looking for i think.  This will help you expedite, expand and go in which direction you want from there, by being a very adjustable MEAN stack scaffold using MOngoose, having CRUD examples, and even Bootstrap Jade SASS front end to help facilitate if you want to use it.

You would separate out your admin site as one of the MVC sections, and so forth, just like you would on any other MVC site pretty much, you can just follow the code standards in the [documentation](https://github.com/wolfdogg/expressBuilder/wiki) there.